# How to Hide and Show Gridview table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2015

i'm using asp.net gridview and ajax calendar extender. For example, the user select date like 19/8/16 then it will show the date for 19/8/16 only on the gridview table. But the problem is i dont know what code to hide and show for gridview. Anyone knows how to hide and show the gridview?

Output:

[image]

Asp.net code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ViewAppliedLeaveByDate.aspx.cs" Inherits="BookReservation.ViewLeave.ViewAppliedLeaveByDate" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <h3>View Leave Application By Start Date</h3>
    <asp:Label ID="lblSearchStartDate" runat="server" CssClass="labelClass" Text="Search By Start Date:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbSearchStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="tbSearchStartDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="tbSearchStartDate" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="gvVALD" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDSSearchStartDate" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StaffName" HeaderText="StaffName" SortExpression="StaffName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StartDate" HeaderText="StartDate" SortExpression="StartDate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Start Leave Period" HeaderText="Start Leave Period" SortExpression="Start Leave Period" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EndDate" HeaderText="EndDate" SortExpression="EndDate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="End Leave Period" HeaderText="End Leave Period" SortExpression="End Leave Period" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NumDays" HeaderText="NumDays" SortExpression="NumDays" />
        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
    <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDSSearchStartDate" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LeaveManagementCS %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Staff.StaffName, LeaveType.Type, LeaveApplications.StartDate, LeavePeriod.Description AS [Start Leave Period], LeaveApplications.EndDate, LeavePeriod.Description AS [End Leave Period], LeaveApplications.NumDays FROM LeaveApplications INNER JOIN LeavePeriod ON LeaveApplications.StartLeavePeriodId = LeavePeriod.LeavePeriodId AND LeaveApplications.EndLeavePeriodId = LeavePeriod.LeavePeriodId INNER JOIN LeaveType ON LeaveApplications.LeaveTypeId = LeaveType.Id INNER JOIN Staff ON LeaveApplications.StaffId = Staff.StaffId"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Asp.net.cs code:

```
public partial class ViewAppliedLeaveByDate : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to query your database for the date you mentioned in your question and you need to refill the gridview on `tbSearchStartDate` text changed event

Comment: on which condition based you want to hide ?

Answer (score 0):

make a textchanged event on textbox "tbSearchStartDate" with autopostback property to true and bind the grid again by supply your selected date to the query

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the Visible property of the GridView control to show\hide it:

```
gvVALD.Visible = false;
```